# Gitlab CI Push from Project A to Project B

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two projects:

- Project A
- Project B

**Goal:**

When I push to project A and the build succeeds, I want to have my gitlab job pull down project B, make changes, and push those changes back up to Project B.

**What Works So Far:**

- Project A passes the build
- Project A's job is able to `git clone` Project B
- Project A's job is able to make the necessary changes to the locally cloned Project B
- Project A's job is able to commit changes to the local git repo
- When I run the gitlab runner **locally**, Project A's job is able to push changes to the master branch of Project B; this is exactly what I want.

**What Does NOT Work So Far:**

- When running on gitlab runners on hosted gitlab, Project A's job is not able to push changes to Project B's master branch

**The Resulting Error of the Failed Job on Gitlab:**

```
remote: You are not allowed to upload code.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/<username>/<gitRepoName>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

**What I've Done to Get Thus Far:**

- I've used Deploy Tokens & Keys
- I've used personal access tokens

**Edit**:

Here is part of my gitlab-ci yaml file where i've added gitlab, site-wide ssh keys:

```
update-other-repo:
  image: alpine:3.14.0
  stage: repo-update
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache git curl bash openssh-client
    - mkdir ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo $GITLAB_CI_PUBKEY > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    - echo $GITLAB_CI_PRIVATE_KEY > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-agent
    - git config --global user.email "projectupdater@gmail.com"
    - git config --global user.name "ProjectUpdater CI"
    - git clone https://${PROJECT_USERNAME}:${PROJECT_PASSWORD}@gitlab.com/<username>/<projectName>.git
    - cd <projectName>
  script:
    - git status
    - git add .
    - git commit -m '[skip ci] updating repo'
    - git push --force origin master
```

Is there a solution to this problem I'm facing? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: where do you specify tokens? please show that part of code(maybe ci file). besides, i suggest use docker container with your ssh credentials, and clone using ssh protacal.

Comment: i've tried a couple things, @LeiYang. I've added both the deploy tokens and keys to the ci/cd variables. i've even generated ssh for my gitlab, site-wide profile and added those as ci/cd variables. I'll add what i've done, though

Comment: seems you haven't used docker.  strongly suggest not mess the runner's envrionment with your keys. try always use https:token@ or docker with ssh.

Comment: Could you expand, @LeiYang? I'm using the alpine image

Comment: where did you clone the repo? it's better to clone, commit and push in the same job scripts. and make sure use the ssh protocal.

Comment: @LeiYang, i added more of the script

Comment: you should clone git@...git(which i said repeatedly the **git protocal**), not https....

Comment: So i went with your suggestion, @LeiYang, but it didn't work. Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Comment: you should also configure `known_hosts` file(this is knowledge of ssh, do some search, i strongly recommend you use prebuilt docker, with ssh, not configure ssh from gitlab env)